# Devise session after nginx proxy pass to different domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, nginx, devise, proxy

The goal is to map mask_domain.com to masp.original_domain.com/something. In order to achieve this goal i've set up my nginx for mask_domain.com as follows (this is a rails app):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mask_domain.com;

  location /assets {
     proxy_pass http://mask.original_domain.com/assets;
  }

  location /uploads {
    proxy_pass http://mask.original_domain.com/uploads;
  }

  location /something {
    proxy_pass http://mask.original_domain.com;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://mask.original_domain.com/something/;
  }
}
```

To authenticate I use Devise. I cannot log in and I don't see any cookies being set. Probably because:

```
  MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_my_app_session', :domain => :all
```

and for :domain => :all it really is '.original_domain.com'

I will appreciate any tips or help :-)

Answer (score 1):

After I posted the question I started to think about cookie rewrites in nginx... and i solved it :-)
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_domain

I just added to the server block:

```
proxy_cookie_domain .original_domain.com .mask_domain.com;
```

Now the session persists cross-domain.